# Zorn's Lemma in an Oxtoby's theorem

Tags: game-theory, axiom-of-choice, baire-category

I'm reading a theorem due to Oxtoby about the link between the Baire spaces and the Choquet Game. I found it in Kechris, Classical Descriptive Set Theory, pag. 43.

I can't understand what he means with "transitive exaustion argument" in the second part of the proof. The Zorn's Lemma argument clearly works for construct the family required, but can it be avoid?

[image: theorem oxtoby]

Comment: It says "**transfinite** exhaustive argument" simply means that you enumerate all the relevant sets, and by transfinite recursion you construct the counterexample. To some extent, this is kind of like proving Zorn's lemma from the well-ordering theorem/the axiom of choice.

Comment: I imagined so. In the end, we need some form of uncountable choice in this proof.